# WCF test/Smoke test

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I wish to have a test to insure my WCF service is up and running.

I found this:

```
[OperationContract]
public void Ping(){}
```

I put that in my IService, but not the Service.svc?
How do I know it works? Do I put in a button and a text box in my User Interface that calls this method, and have some sort of statement in that ping method that places a value in the text box if that Ping method runs? Here is what I propose:

IService:

```
[OperationContract]
public void Ping()
{
    TextBox.Text = "Okay".ToString();
}
```

User Interface:

```
private void btnPing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    public void Ping()
}
```

Comment: How you can call this method directly in you test method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For testing your WCF service up and running make a windows form(as you have previously done) 
Write click on project/solution and choose **Add service reference.**

Paste your service url in address textbox (Ex. www.xyz.com/abcservice.svc or www.xyz.com/true?wsdl) Change the namespace in same wizard.(default would be ServiceReference1).

Now use your button click event as what your were doing then call this method.

```
private void btnPing_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    ServiceReference1.yourServiceClassName obj = new ServiceReference1.yourServiceClassName();
obj.ping();
//Check your output if that is not throwing any exception.
}
```

If no error or exception then everything is OK.

Comment: So in this case, I can use my existing WPF user interface, add a button 'Ping Test'. add another Service Reference called 'ServiceReferenceTest' pasting in the address from the  UI App.config such as http://projectname.azurewebsites.net/'MyProjectServiceName1'

Comment: yes your service.svc from service appconfig file not UI

Comment: So in this case, I can use my existing WPF user interface, add a button 'Ping Test'. Then I add another Service Reference called 'ServiceReferenceTest' pasting in the address from the  UI App.config file such as http://projectname.azurewebsites.net/'MyProjectService'   and I add the method to the original MyProjectService.svc.cs and add  another operation contract method signature  in the ImyProjectService.cs?

Comment: one second i am sharing you a simple tutorial otherwise conversation will go to long

Comment: My WCF layer has no App.config file, it exists only in my UI layer.

Comment: and where is your WCF is hosting ? in current project or any other service

Comment: The projects layers are all local, the service is in Azure

Comment: so take the address of service form app.config for service which is running on azure

Comment: I should probably look into that tutorial you mentioned. Don't want to waste anymore of your time.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UcmD1SfIayM&index=3&list=PL6n9fhu94yhVxEyaRMaMN_-qnDdNVGsL1 go with this tutorial you will get to know  how to take address and test client

Comment: Part of my problem was me not correctly explaining it. I needed to publish the service to Azure, and them make sure the endpoint address in the UI App.config file is the service's azure address, not the local host address.